How to Detect Local Storage Changes in react-native-webview for React Native App
I am developing a React Native app that incorporates a React application via react-native-webview. My goal is to synchronize changes made to the language key in the web view’s local storage with the async storage in my React Native app.
Here’s the current setup:

React Native App: This is the main application.
React App: Runs inside a react-native-webview in the React Native app.

I need to detect whenever the language key in the web view’s local storage changes, and subsequently update the async storage in the React Native app accordingly.
I attempted to periodically check for changes in the local storage by setting up intervals within the React native app (with injected JS). This approach does successfully detect changes, but I am aware that using intervals is not efficient or the most effective method for this purpose. I am looking for a more optimal approach.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Post a message from React app to native side when language changes.
window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({language: "en"}))

Then listen changes on native side.
<WebView
...
  onMessage={(event) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data)
  }}
/>

See doc for details.
